# How to authenticate a user with the official Joomla 4 REST API?

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-api, authentication

I am developing a mobile app that needs to authenticate users with a Joomla 4 site. I want to use the official Joomla REST API to do this, but I couldn’t find any information about how to authenticate a user and get an API Token with the official Joomla REST API. Can anyone provide some guidance on how to do this?
I know the API token can be generated in the user profile, but that is not relevant to my question. the API does not have a Login function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm exactly in the same situtation. Mobile app users need to log in with their Joomla credentials. Seems like an obvious feature for a REST api. We used the cAPI plugin which offered this for Joomla 3.x but not Joomla 4.

Could you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

See the Joomla manual, in particular the "Using the PHP cURL Functions" part (because you probably run it outside the Joomla framework) : https://manual.joomla.org/docs/general-concepts/webservices#using-the-php-curl-functions

An interesting article about using the Web Services API: https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/march-2023/playing-with-the-joomla-api-part-1

Comment: To use the API (for example, in mobile Apps), the user must register first; after that, the login function must return the API Token. But apparently, this is not possible.

Comment: That's correct. At this moment, the Token functionality for access is limited to Super User accounts.